# How to add Group to Ability in JosephSilber/bouncer?

Tags: php, laravel, acl

I wanted to create groups of abilities; I made a custom Model App\Models\Role and App\Models\Ability to override Bouncer's.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Silber\Bouncer\Database\Role as BouncerRole;

class Role extends BouncerRole
{

}

namespace App\Models;

use Silber\Bouncer\Database\Ability as BouncerAbility;

class Ability extends BouncerAbility
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'title', 'entity_id', 'entity_type', 'only_owned', 'options', 'scope', 'group_id'
    ];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
}
```

But when I querying Role::with('abilities')->get() albilities are empty although when I use Bouncer's methods abilities appear

Comment: Have you [registered](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer#custom-models) your custom role/ability models with Bouncer?

Comment: Where I can do that?

Comment: I linked to it in my last comment. Here's the link again: https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer#custom-models